# iText error while trying to set an image field

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText 5.3.4 and trying to set an image field, the below code is what Bruno suggested that I use however I am getting an error of "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List".
I see no documentation on how to write the code the way that the api is asking for.
Does anyone have an idea on how this should be written????
Or how to send an image to an image field?

```
Rectangle rect = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName)[0].position;
int page = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName)[0].page;
image1.scaleAbsolute(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
img.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
stamper.getOverContent(page).addImage(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

The return from `getFieldPositions` is of type [`List<AcroFields.FieldPosition>`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getFieldPositions%28java.lang.String%29), so the complaint is valid. You should use `.get(0)` rather than `[0]` to reference the first item in the collection.

A simple refactoring might be:

```
List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName);
Rectangle rect = positions.get(0).position;
int page = positions.get(0).page;
image1.scaleAbsolute(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
img.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
stamper.getOverContent(page).addImage(img);
```

Comment: I tried to make this changes but the code errors out,  This is what I tried:
Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) form.getFieldPositions(fieldName).get(0);
    int page = form.getFieldPositions(fieldName).get(0); //Errors our here as it no longer returns an int
    img.scaleAbsolute(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    img.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
    stamper.getOverContent(page).addImage(img); //if I change the page to an obj, this line errors out as page is no longer a valid arguement
could you write that out so that I can see what you are saying? Code sample please

Comment: that compiled no worries, thank you, I will let you know how it works out